# How do you find all changesets in TFS 2013 that have not been merged using C#?

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, changeset, candidate

I'm having problems finding all changesets in TFS 2013 using C# that have not been merged. I already tried using GetMergeCandidates but it does not find nested changesets, which I also want. 
Here is an example of the nested changesets:

[image: Nested Changesets]

So, for example, in the above, only changeset 30650 shows up as a changeset when I run my program.

In short, I want to find all changesets that haven't been merged. Please help!

Edit: Currently, I'm trying this:

```
`var mergeCandidates = versionControl.GetMergeCandidates(@firstBranch, @secondBranch, RecursionType.Full);`
```

where firstBranch and secondBranch are put in by the user for merge comparison.

Comment: What is the command line call that you're using at the moment?

Comment: Hi Alicia! I'm trying to write it in C#, not in the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Alicia,
See my edit above for what I'm currently running.
Any advice?